# Incorrect intent recognition for similar words in rasa nlu

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

When the user asks **out_of_scope** question which contains some keyword(helping words to construct the sentence) which is used in defined intent then it chooses the defined intent(I have not used any entity approach).

config.yml

```
# Configuration for Rasa NLU.
# https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/components/
language: en
pipeline: supervised_embeddings

# Configuration for Rasa Core.
# https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/policies/
policies:
  - name: MemoizationPolicy
    max_history: 5
  - name: KerasPolicy
    epochs: 400
    batch_size: 100
    validation_split: 0.2
    max_history: 5
  - name: MappingPolicy
  - name: "FallbackPolicy"
    nlu_threshold: 0.7
    core_threshold: 0.5
    fallback_action_name: "action_default_fallback"
```

Below is my  intent

```
intent: ask_faq_how_many _vegetarian_restaurants_are_there_nearby
- how many vegetarian restaurants are there nearby
- vegetarian restaurants near by
- please tell me how many vegetarian restaurants are there
```

If the user asks :

1. “what vegetarian food option do i have”?
2. “do you like vegetarian food”?
3. "vegetarian food"

then the nlu pick ask_faq_how_many _vegetarian_restaurants_are_there_nearby as intent .

Above 3 questions are not related to any intent and user can have many other chitchats using above keyword and training it all keyword might take a long time.
Is there any way we can tell nlu to not to pick intent just based on a few keywords?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you're asking for is possible.

Every machine learning algorithm works by learning to predict something with the data that you feed it. So, if your training data has the word `vegetarian` associated with only a single intent then it **will** predict it as that intent. No way around that.

But, if you want it to predict something else then you could try putting in more intents with similar data so that the model can learn to differentiate between different intents that share their vocabulary.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried having an `out_of_scope` intent and putting those chitchat utterances in there? I can't promise it will be very good since there is a lot of crossover, but if you don't have anywhere else for those inputs to be classified, they definitely will go into that intent.

Comment: yes, I have used out_of_scope intents also but i can't cover all keywords by adding in there because the user can ask anything other than the out_of_scope intents also.

Comment: is there any policy setting or pipeline which can improve this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest building an intent that maps as many entities as possible. So, within your custom action for this intent if these entities are not found in the input, then you know that the mapping is wrong in spite of a strong confidence based on keywords used.

In your case ask_faq_how_many_vegetarian_restaurants_are_there_nearby, create training examples that map (1) the number aspect, and (2) that you want shops that are in fact restaurant(s).

```
- how [many](number) vegetarian [restaurant](shops)s are there nearby 
- are there [many](number) vegetarian [restaurant](shops)s nearby
```

The more specific the intent becomes, chit chat messages with the right keywords would get low confidence, and the missing entities should confirm that the matching is wrong.

Hope this helps!